# Is there a way to execute a function without holding the whole script? (PHP)

Tags: php

My web server only allow 30 secounds for timeout, and I have some big loops that actually takes minutes.

The script purpose is to send notifications to an app.

```
$queryGCM = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM toks WHERE pid = '$pid' AND method = 'GOOGLECLOUDMESSAGE' ORDER by ids")or die(mysql_error());
while($notiar = mysql_fetch_array( $queryGCM  ))    
{
    sendGCM(*******);
}
$queryAPNS = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM toks WHERE pid = '$pid ' AND method != 'GOOGLECLOUDMESSAGE' ORDER by ids")or die(mysql_error());
while($notiar = mysql_fetch_array( $queryAPNS ))    
{

    sendAPNS(******);

}
```

This acript is taking alot more than 30 minutes, im sure there is a way to split the script in  a way that it would actually finish the loop.

Any suggestiong?
Thank you!

Comment: Run the task as a cron job rather than from the webserver

Comment: You can use the PECL lib - pthreads which allows you multithreading, so you can put these parts in another thread

Comment: if your hosting limits are not sufficient, surely you should change hosting?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function to increase server execution time  [**max_execution_time()**](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

it will helps you, as in every server we can set execution time for file. Which server are you using?